# Cocos2d (iOS) + SneakyInput. The best way to handle joystick (joypad) events?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have seen at least two ways:

1)to handle the touch screen events

2)to schedule a repeatable task which will send a joypad state to an object. The original link:

[link](http://www.qcmat.com/sneakyinput-joystick-dpad-and-buttons-for-cocos2d/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have chosen the second way. But additionally I use a timer instance for repeating pressing button event.

I have also created a constants which mean all the possible joypad states (sneakyinput joypad states are represented by numbers by default)